# Using value from previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some problem with using value from previous row (i kinda don't know how to do it).

I want to do something like :

```
 update test SET amount = (select amountAfter 
 from rozl (Here i want to take it from previous row = this ID - 1)
```

I got primary key id, whole table is sorted by id.
What I want to do is :

Take value from previous row from Column name amountAfter and insert it into amount in actual id.

Here is example

```
    id  amount   used   destroyed  amountAfter
     1     100     50          30          20
     2      20      5           1          14
```

Comment: Check out the windowing function `LAG`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option using a `join` assuming your `id` fields are sequential:

```
update t1
set t1.amount = t2.amountafter
from test t1 join
     test t2 on t2.id = t1.id - 1
```

---

If you are using `2012` or higher, look at using `lag`:

```
with cte as (
    select id, amount, lag(amount) over (order by id) prevamount
    from test
    )
update cte 
set amount = prevamount 
where prevamount is not null
```

---

And I guess to be complete, `2008` would work with `row_number` if the numbers aren't sequential (using a combination of both approaches):

```
with cte as (
    select id, amount, row_number() over (order by id) rn
    from test
    )
update t1
set t1.amount = t2.amount
from cte t1 join
     cte t2 on t2.rn = t1.rn - 1
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that this depends on the ids being sequential (none missing)

Comment: @Nicarus -- Good point.  Edited, perhaps I was taking this too literally: `Here i want to take it from previous row = this ID - 1`

Comment: @sgeddes Could you gave me any contact to you? I just had one more question, probably answer will be a lot easier so I don't want to start new thread for no reason.